# Can 2 Debezium Connectors read from same source at the same time?

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium

As the title says, I have 2 seperate servers and I want both connectors to read from same source to write to their respective topic. A single connector works well. When I create another one in a different server they seem to be running but no data flow occurs for both.
My question is, is that possible to run 2 debezium connectors that read from same source? I couldn't find any information about this topic in documentation.

Edit: I've tested it with oracle database and never seen it's working well. Definitely wouldn't recommend using it especially in oracle.

Comment: Yes, you can run multiple Debezium source connectors that capture changes from the same source database but we generally don't recommend this unless it's absolutely necessary.  Certain configuration values need to be unique to each connector so that each connector isn't sharing state with one another.  Which connector are you using?

Comment: I'm using oracle connector. your comment answers my question actually, if you write it as an answer I can accept it. @Naros

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So generally speaking, Debezium does not recommend that you use multiple connectors per database source and prefer that you adjust your connector configuration instead.  We understand that isn't always the case when you have different business use cases at play.

That said, it's important that if you do deploy multiple connectors you properly configure each connector so that it doesn't share state such as the same database history topic, etc.

For certain database platforms, having multiple source connectors really doesn't apply any real burden to the database, such as MySQL.  But other databases like Oracle, running multiple connectors can have a pretty substantial impact.

When an Oracle connector streams changes, it starts an Oracle LogMIner mining session.  This session is responsible for loading, reading, parsing, and preparing the contents of the data read in a special in-memory table that the connector uses to generate change events.  When you run multiple connectors, you will have concurrent Oracle LogMiner sessions happening and each session will be consuming its own share of PGA memory to support the steps taken by Oracle LogMiner.  Depending on your database's volatility, this can be stressful on the database server since Oracle specifically assigns one LogMiner session to a CPU.

For an Oracle environment, I highly recommend you avoid using multiple connectors *unless* you are needing to stream changes from different PDBs within the same instance since there is really no technical reason why you should want to read, load, parse, and generate change data for the same redo entries multiple times, once per connector deployment.

Comment: Hello, good answer. What about deploying the exact same Debezium/Sql Server connector (embedded into Spring Boot and Apache Camel) as a Docker container on two different OpenShift clusters?